# Set mstest working directory

Tags: command-line, mstest

I'm trying to create a powershell script that executes my tests for my solution. I have 2 assemblies with tests in them. The problem is that in the tests I load files and the tests search in the working directory. When I run the tests through VS IDE I have no problem as the tests run from the bin folder where all the files are copied to. When I run mstest through powershell/command line, it creates a new folder in the what ever my current location is. So even if I navigate to the the bin folder before running, mstest runs from "bin\<`User`>_<`Machine Name`> <`Date`> <`Time`>\Out" and thus can't find the files I need to load.

Is there a way to set the working directory for mstest? I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything. (Hopefully I'm missing something).